# How can I access a variable from inside an anonymous mouse-event function?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I'm trying to access the variable **myvar** from outside like so:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var myvar = winHeight() + scrollY() - e.pageY;
}); 
console.log(myvar);
```

But Chrome's javascript console keeps saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: myvar is not defined all-products:203
(anonymous function)"

What am I doing wrong? How do I access this variable outside this function?

**EDIT:** I've realised that what I was attempting to do isn't realisable. I have since changed my strategy completely and the code works fine now. (Thank you James and especially Vlad for your help!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a job for javascript events. Basically you have a global variable which will be updated on mouse move. After you update the variable you have to let other components know that the variable is ready for processing.

The code:

```
var myVar; // the global variable

// the function that will be caled when myVar has been changed
var myVarChangedHandler = function() {
    console.log('myVar variable has been changed: ' + myVar);
}

// bind the event to the above event handler
$('body').bind('MyVarChangedEvent', myVarChangedHandler);

// instal mouse move event handler on document
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    myVar = winHeight() + scrollY() - e.pageY;
    $('body').trigger('MyVarChangedEvent');
});
```

**UPDATE**

Removed the `var` keyword form the movemove event handler.

The code that depends on myVar should be put in the `myVarChangedHandler` function.

I'll try to explain the best i can your code, the flaw in it
and how you should be solving the problem using an analogy.
Let's take the following code (global variable corrected)

```
var myvar;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    myvar = winHeight() + scrollY() - e.pageY;
}); 
console.log(myvar);
```

Let's say you, the programmer, are a team leader in a web development department
in some unnamed company and you have a list of tasks to be done in a day of work (
the tasks in our analogy is to update `myvar` everytime the mouse moves)
You have at your disposal a repository (`var myvar`) and 2 developers:

- developer John (`function(e) { myVar = ... };`)
- developer Ken (`console.log(myvar)`)

09:00 You come to the office in the morning (user opens the page)

09:05 You power up the server / repository

```
var myvar;
```

09:10 You tell John: 
John, please do this tasks and everytime you complete each task
uploaded it to the repository, and go home after your hours are finished

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    myvar = winHeight() + scrollY() - e.pageY;
});
```

09:11 You tell Ken:
Ken, please test the code in the repository right now and go home after you
have finished testing

```
console.log(myvar);
```

(at this time, Ken sees that the repository is empty and goes home - that's because
John didn't had time to solve even on task in a minute so Ken has nothing to test)

09:12 You go home

At 09:12 there's only John at the office doing the tasks, You and Ken have left home
because you don't have anything else to do.
This also happens to your code. You output the value of `myvar` but you haven't even moved the mouse
so, of course, the value is `undefined`

To solve this we add some modifications:

09:00 You come to the office in the morning

09:05 You power up the server (repository)

09:10 You tell John:

```
John, please do this tasks and everytime you complete each task
uploaded it to the repository and tell Ken to test the code.
Go home after you have finished
```

09:11 You tell Ken:

```
Ken, each time John tells you that he has completed a task,
fetch the code from the repository and test it.
Go home after he has finished
```

09:12 You go home

at 09:12 both John and Ken are at the office doing their job.

In the above case ken is `myVarChangedHandler = function() {...};`

When John tells Ken that he completed the task an actual event occurs (the telling),
when Ken acknowleges John signal he starts testing (Ken is the event handler)

This is how event driven architecture in javascript works.
I would advise you to ditch jquery, mootools, etc... and start learning the core concepts
and the basics. Reinvent the wheel a few times then go back to jquery.
I hope i explained enough for you to understand.

Comment: That didn't work either.. gave me the error message "myVar variable has been changed: undefined "   (even though i corrected your misspelling of myVar on line 13)

Comment: @MoRamzan i copy pasted your code and forgot to remove the var keyword in the mouse move event handler. i updated the answer. try it again

Comment: This seems to work, bit still doesn't let me access the **myVar** variable externally. For this to happen, the text following "This is an external change: " should update... http://jsfiddle.net/MoRamzan/Q9NBQ/4/

Comment: @MoRamzan It's not possible what you are trying to achieve. That's why i resorted to using events.

Comment: @MoRamzan you get undefined results because you output the value of `myVar` before that var has been changed by the mouse move event handler. You first need to understand the way that javascript handles events and executes it's code

Comment: @MoRamzan i tryed to explain a bit more the problem and the solution

Answer (score 2):

You will need to move the variable to an outer scope which is accessible by both bits of code.

```
var myvar = -1;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    myvar = winHeight() + scrollY() - e.pageY;
}); 

console.log(myvar);
```

Comment: If I do that, I don't get the error message. But then **myvar** doesn't update as the mouse is moved around. If I put the console statement inside the function then I do get the output in real-time, but i want to access it outside...

Comment: Are you sure your code is exactly as above?  Assuming the `mousemove` code is working properly, this will work.  Be sure you removed the `var` declaration from within your handler.

Comment: This is my code: var myvar = -1;
 $(document).mousemove(function(e){
  myvar = winHeight() + scrollY() - e.pageY;
 }); 
 console.log(myvar);

Comment: And you are sure the `mousemove` bit is working properly other than this?  What are `winHeight` and `scrollY`?

Comment: Working example without your two custom methods:  http://jsfiddle.net/Q9NBQ/  click anywhere to see the current value of the variable.

Comment: winHeight and scrollY are return variables from other external functions.

Comment: My code updates fine inside the function in real-time, but I can't access it outside AND have it update a global variable.

Comment: Then there is something more going on here which is not included in the code posted.  See if you can recreate your code in a `jsfiddle`.

Comment: No - doesn't work in JSFiddle either! Made a silly mistake of running old code in jsfiddle lol

Comment: If you add some way of seeing the value of the variable, such as a click handler I added, yo uwill see that it is updating the variable.  What makes you think it isn't?  http://jsfiddle.net/Q9NBQ/5/

Comment: your alert message is coming from inside the function and not from the outside call :-(

Comment: No, the alert is coming from inside a different function.  I promise you the variable is updated, the issue has to be in the way you are checking if it has been updated.