# Getting Value of Variable from Inside Mouse Event Function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, mouse, easeljs

EDIT: I was tempted to delete this question when I had an epiphany regarding the way javascript handles variables. The "CorrectAnswer" variable will be accessible outside the function once the the function changes it. If I do something to check on the variable after the function is run, like clicking a button, it shows the correct value of the variable, just like I had wanted. If the Editors want to delete this question, I have no objection. I am happy to leave it up, though, if it helps someone else have the same epiphany, if they face this same issue. I apologize for my "newbiness", but I am learning! Thanks to all of you...you do all of us a great service!

I am working on a puzzle project in Adobe Animate HTML5 Canvas. I am trying to pass a variable value from inside of a mouse event to the outside of the mouse event. Specifically, I would like to get the value for "CorrectAnswer" passed to the outside of the function.

I understand the concept of variable scope. So far, I have seen this done with jquery (e.g. [How can I access a variable from inside an anonymous mouse-event function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496014/how-can-i-access-a-variable-from-inside-an-anonymous-mouse-event-function)), but I'm wondering if it can be done within the Easeljs framework used in Adobe Animate HTML5Canvas. I have tried defining the variable outside of the function and other methods that involve a "return CorrectAnswer" and another function, but to no avail.

```
function onMouseUp(evt){
  var item = evt.currentTarget;
  item.drag = false;
  var pt = item.localToLocal(item.dot.x, item.dot.y, 
    item.TargetAnswer);
  if(item.TargetAnswer.hitTest(pt.x, pt.y) ){
    item.x = item.TargetAnswer.x;
    item.y = item.TargetAnswer.y;
    CorrectAnswer=true;}
  else
    {CorrectAnswer=false;}
}
```

Of course, a console.log(CorrectAnswer); inside the function produces the desired value. Placed outside, it produces only the initially defined value of the variable. Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To define the variable outside the function should work:

```js
let correctAnswer = false;
const onMouseUp = e => {
    correctAnswer = true;
};
document.querySelector('button.set').addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
document.querySelector('button.output').addEventListener('click', e => console.log(correctAnswer));
```

```html
<button class="output">output correctAnswer</button>
<button class="set">set correctAnswer to true</button>
```

You may wanna provide us with more information if the problem still exists.
greetz

Comment: Thank you. I apologize, I am new to this. In Adobe Animate, I don't know where to put the HTML you used for the button class.